# How to run another rscript using a button on another script in SHINY?

Tags: r, shiny

How to run a code of an R script by clicking the actionButton in SHINY? The button would call the script saved in the same directory and run the functions of that script. I have tried using source("code.R") but I am not able to do that successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the code has not been shared, I tried making a dummy shiny app and tested it out. Let me know where you are deviating. Please share the error which you are dealing with meanwhile.

test.R:

```
bins <- function(n_bin){
 x    <- faithful[, 2]
 bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = n_bin + 1)

 # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
 hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
}
```

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

# Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  sliderInput("bins",
              "Number of bins:",
              min = 1,
              max = 50,
              value = 30),
  actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
),

# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("distPlot")
))))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
 observeEvent(input$goButton,{
 source("test.R")
 output$distPlot <- renderPlot({    

  bins(input$bins)
})})})
```